# Многосайтовость и папка local в bitrix

Tags: битрикс

После установки битрикса не обнаружил папку `local`, который нам нужен для многосайтовости.

Как делать так, чтобы появилась папка `local`? Или его нужно самим создать вручную?

Answer (score 1):

папка local создаётся вручную.
структура папки local имеет схожую структуру с папкой bitrix.
Очень часто именно local запихивают в git.

Answer (score 0):

Папка `local` не устанавливается системой. Она может быть создана при необходимости самостоятельно.